# Ireport: Preventing detail splitting affects the page total

Tags: mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

When i try  to prevent the detail from splitting it affects the page total.
This is what is happening:
The summary is done in the current page and the extra row is showm on the next page.
But I want the sum to be calculated on the page where the forwarded row appears.

e.g:

In page 1: I have the balance of V1+V2+V3+V4 but V4 appears in Page 2

Normally I should have in page 1 the balance of V1+V2+V3 and in Page 2 the balance of V4+V5+V6.

Can someone help me out !
[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem. Did you found a solution?

Comment: If I have good memories this is a case of miscalculation of forwarded rows by ireport. Whenever a row spread over two consecutives pages ireport becomes confused. Instead of using split type= prevent as option in the detail band , set it to split type= Stretch. Then create a dummy group (by primary key of the row) with group header and footer enabled that will act as a container for each row . Dummy group option are: reprint header=true, Min Height to start new= value of detail band height, Footer Position= normal, Keep together= true.

Comment: Now if each row is processed as group and will be forwarded to next page it cannot fit a the current one. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> If I have good memories this is a case of miscalculation of forwarded
>   rows by ireport. Whenever a row spread over two consecutives pages
>   ireport becomes confused. Instead of using split type= prevent as
>   option in the detail band , set it to split type= Stretch. Then create
>   a dummy group (by primary key of the row) with group header and footer
>   enabled that will act as a container for each row . Dummy group option
>   are: reprint header=true, Min Height to start new= value of detail
>   band height, Footer Position= normal, Keep together= true.
>
> Now if each row is processed as group and will be forwarded to next
>   page it cannot fit a the current one. Hope it helps

In which band you has added the "Page Total"? I have same problem, and I tried your solution, but, the problem persists, the total is increased with the value from next page.

My report:

[image]

Comment: Questions: 1. In the Group properties on the dummy group have you enabled KEEP TOGETHER ? if not do it.

Comment: Questions: 2. In the Group properties of the dummy group what is the value of MIN HEIGHT TO START NEW PAGE ?

Comment: Hi Edar, as you know this is a tricky issue and also depend on you specific report design and other options. I did this for the general ledger report and I used the column footer to show the total but for the general journal (page footer) . The key answer is grouping each row by its primary key. If you have to group for example by Month; you first group by each row(dummy) then by month.

Comment: 1- Yes, i did
2- "MIN HEIGHT TO START NEW PAGE", same detail size;